# Authorization using Cognito with IAM and Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I am trying to create an application where a user can sign in and then have access to certain api resources based on their roles.

Users are moved into groups in the user pool and each group has a custom IAM role.

I have used to amplify CLI tools to create the authentication, api gateway and lambda function.
This is the API set up in amplify

```
? Please select from one of the below mentioned services: REST
? Please select the REST API you would want to update standardApi
? What would you like to do Update path
? Please select the path you would want to edit /std
? Provide a path (e.g., /book/{isbn}): /std
? Choose a Lambda source Use a Lambda function already added in the current Ampl
ify project
? Choose the Lambda function to invoke by this path standardFunction
? Restrict API access Yes
? Restrict access by? Individual Groups
? Select groups: standard
? What kind of access do you want for standard users? create, read, update, dele
te
Successfully updated resource
```

The resources are created as expected when checked in the console.

The trouble is that when attempting to call the API, I am receiving a MissingAuthenticationTokenException

This is the call

```
const apiName = 'standardApi';
const path = '/std';
const myInit = {
    headers: {},
    response: false
};
API.get(apiName, path, myInit)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response);
});
```

My understanding is that the Amplify sdk should automatically populate the request headers with the correct authentication values.

If I attempt passing in the access token manually,

```
headers: {
    Authorization: (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()
},
```

I get IncompleteSignatureException, with the message

```
Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.
```

Trying

```
headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()}
},
```

results in IncompleteSignatureException with no message.

Other posts have suggested that the endpoint may no be specified correctly, if I remove auth from the api in the console and redeploy, the endpoint is hit as expected. Futhermore, if I create a custom authorizer with the cognito user pool, the endpoint is hit correctly when signed in and a bearer token in passed.

It's just the IAM case that is not working.

Inspecting the ID token shows that the correct username, groups and roles are being passed in.

```
"cognito:groups": Array [ "standard" ]
"cognito:preferred_role": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/region-*_*********-standardGroupRole"
"cognito:roles": Array [ "arn:aws:iam::************:role/region-*_*********-standardGroupRole"]
"cognito:username": "0a******-****-****-****-************"
```

The Amplify configure step is being done with auto-generated aws-exports file, which contains correct entries for user pool, identity pool and client app.

Comment: You have to sign your request as described in the [docs][1]


  [1]: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js#signing-a-request-from-lambda

Comment: @OscarNevarez Thanks for this. It looks like it does what I need. I ended up using a lambda authorizer to do the job. [link that I borrowed from a lot](https://github.com/99xt-incubator/cognito-iam-authorizer/blob/master/index.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this can be a little bit late, but I just wanted to do the same thing that you were trying to do.

This is what I had to do to make it work:

- Include authentication components in your UI so your API call is done with the credentials of the authenticated user.
- Be sure to do the API call once you have been authenticated against Cognito (with a user that belong to the group that you specified).
- Don't include any 'Authorization' header (I looked in the code and I found out that no AWS Signature is generated when Authorization header is set).
- Make sure that your lambda code returns CORS headers (I was having an InternalServerErrorException from CloudFront because of this).

Doing this I could see in the Developer console of my Browser that the request was signed and had all the headers needed for the IAM authorization validation that API Gateway does.

I hope this cloud be useful to somebody as it took me a lot of time to figure it out.

Regards,
Andres Llanos

Comment: Only if I could thank you enough! But thank you!!!